# Funcion recursiva para obtener vocales de una palabra (Scala)

Tags: recursión, scala

estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio en el que hay que definir una función recursiva que sea capaz de devolver una cadena con todas las vocales de una cadena usando otra función que indica si un Char es vocal o no:

```
object ej8 {
  def esVocal(letra:Char):Boolean={
    var vocal:Boolean=false
    if(letra=='a' || letra=='e' || letra=='i' || letra=='o' || letra=='u')vocal=true
    return vocal
  }
  def vocales(cadena:String): String={}
```

Me cuesta bastante ver si la función vocales se puede hacer de manera recursiva ya que necesita sí o sí de la función esVocal al ser esta la que comprueba las letras una por una pero no consigo dar con una solución válida sin que se me llene la pila o haga cosas raras, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te aconsejo que accedas a la cadena por índice (`cadena.charAt`). No está bien visto en *programación funcional* y, en muchos casos, existe alguna alternativa mejor. Por ejemplo, se puede usa `s.head` en lugar de `s.charAt(0)`, o `s.tail` en lugar de `s.substring(1)`,

Así mismo, en scala se recomienda no usar el `return` para salir de una función, eso es más típico de *programación imperativa*.

Básicamente, lo que necesitas es crear un *"filtro"*, algo tan simple como:

```
def vocales(cadena: String): String = cadena.filter(esVocal)
```

Podemos crearla como función recursiva, pasando una función de chequeo como argumento, algo así:

```
def filtro(s: String, f: (Char) => Boolean): String =
  if (s.isEmpty)
    ""
  else if (f(s.head))
    s.head + filtro(s.tail, f)
  else
    filtro(s.tail, f)
```

Con lo que nos quedaría finalmente:

```
def vocales(s: String) = filtro(s, esVocal)
```

La función filtro se puede aplicar a más objetos. Podemos crear una función filtro genérica que sirva para cualquier tipo de secuencia:

```
def filtro[A](s: Seq[A], f: (A => Boolean)): Seq[A] = 
  s match {
    case (x +: xs) if f(x) => x +: filtro(xs, f)
    case (_ +: xs) => filtro(xs, f)
    case Nil => Nil
  }
```

Con esta definición, nuestra función `vocales` quedaría así:

```
def vocales(s: String) = filtro(s, esVocal).mkString
```

Por cierto, la función `esVocal` también se podría hacer más simple:

```
def esVocal(c: Char) = "aeiou" contains c
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementar el siguiente pseudocódigo que provee un mecanismo recursivo en el cual se tienen en cuenta 3 factores: una cadena o string que es la fuente o cadena principal, la posición en la cual inicias a recorrer la cadena o string, y por ultimo la pila a la cual añadirás elementos.

```
Funcion obtenerVocales(Cadena fuente, Entero posicion, Pila pila) Devuelve Pila

    Si posicion < fuente.longitud Entonces
        caracter charActual = fuente[posicion];

            Si esVocal(charActual) Entonces
                pila.push(charActual)
            Fin Si

       Devolver obtenerVocales(fuente, posicion + 1, pila)
    Fin Si

    Devolver pila
Fin Funcion
```

Si solo quieres mostrar o imprimir los valores entonces deberías no usar una pila y simplemente imprimir por pantalla cuando sea una vocal, solo pasarías en la función los parámetros de la cadena a obtener las vocales y la posición en la que inicia. Un saludo! :)

Pd: No tengo experiencia en Scala pero creo que con esto puedes resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hola, pero al usar ya una posición se supone que estoy iterando que es lo totalmente opuesto a la recursividad, ¿no? Al final creo haber encontrado un código válido para la función, lo publico por si a alguien le interesa. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: No rompes la regla de recursividad porque la función evalúa un carácter a la vez, hasta llegar al final de la cadena. Por ejemplo en lenguaje C sería más simple con el uso de punteros.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber encontrado una solución válida:

```
def vocales(cadena:String): String={
    if(esVocal(cadena.charAt(0)) && cadena.length()>1){
      return cadena.charAt(0)+vocales(cadena.substring(1))
    }
    else if(!esVocal(cadena.charAt(0)) && cadena.length()>1){
      return vocales(cadena.substring(1))
    }else{
      return cadena
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría que usaras recursion de cola

```
    def vocales(s:String):String={esVocal(s, "")} 
    def esVocal(s:String, r:String):String={
        if(s.isEmpty){
           r
        }
        val letra = s.head
        if(letra=='a' || letra=='e' || letra=='i' || letra=='o' || letra=='u'){
           r += letra
        }
        esVocal(s.tail, r)
    }
```

con eso no deberias tener problemas con la pila de memoria